# Looping to get different data on cards in React

Tags: reactjs, loops

**My data looks like this:**

```
export const data = JSON.parse(`{
  "from": 1,
  "to": 20,
  "count": 10000,
  "_links": {},
  "hits": [
    {
      "recipe": {
        "label": "Paleo Chocolate Covered Caramels",
        "image": "https://media.wincacademy.nl/react/images/final-project/chocolate-caramel.jpeg",
        "url": "http://ourfineday.com/happy-birthday-travis-and-a-recipe-for-chocolate-covered-chocolates/",
        "yield": 12,
        "dietLabels": [

          "Low-Sodium"
        ],
        "healthLabels": [
          "Low Potassium", ETC
        ],
        "cautions": [
          "Tree-Nuts", ETC
        ],
        "ingredientLines": [
          "1/2 cup honey",ETC

        ],
        "ingredients": [
          {
            "text": "1/2 cup honey",ETC
        ],
        "mealType": [
          "lunch/dinner"
        ],
        "dishType": [
          "desserts"
        ], ETC
```

In data, the hits are recipes I have to loop through. I need to put 20 different cards with recipes on a page. I first designed one card in the component RecipeCard. I then import RecipeCard in RecipeListPage which I want to use to show all recipes. To get all the info for a recipe on a card while designing it, I used:

`const recipe = data.hits[0].recipe`

Now I need to get all the different (20) recipes each on a card. I've tried looping with different kinds of functions, but nothing really works. With the current code, I get all the recipe cards on the page, but of course with only 1 same recipe on all of them.

Is there any way in the current code, to make it work: get a different recipe on each card? Or did I design this wrong and is it better to start over again?

```
import { data } from '../utils/data';
import { Tag } from './Tag';
import {
    Text,
    Image,
    Center,
    Card,
    CardBody,
    Stack,
    Flex
} from '@chakra-ui/react';


export const RecipeCard = ({ clickFn }) => {
    const recipe = data.hits[0].recipe

    return (
        <>
            <Center h='100vh'>
                <Card
                    bgColor='white'
                    borderRadius={15}
                    overflow='hidden'
                    w='xsm'
                    h='md'
                    onClick={() => clickFn(recipe)}
                    _hover={{ transform: 'scale(1.01' }}
                >
                    <CardBody w='18em' p={0}>
                        <Stack direction='column' spacing='2px'>
                            <Image
                                objectFit='cover'
                                h='10rem'
                                src={recipe.image}
                                borderTopLeftRadius={15}
                                borderTopRightRadius={15}>
                            </Image>

                            <Flex flexDirection='column' align='center' gap={1}>
                                <Text textTransform='uppercase'>{recipe.mealType}</Text>
                                <Text fontSize={18} fontWeight='bold' textAlign='center'>
                                    {recipe.label}
                                </Text>
  
                                <Flex gap={1}>
                                    {recipe.healthLabels.filter(
                                        label => label.includes('Vegetarian')).map(filteredLabel => (
                                            <Tag
                                                key={filteredLabel}
                                                textTransform='uppercase'
                                                fontSize={10}
                                                bgColor='yellow.400'
                                                color='gray.900'
                                            >
                                            Vegetarian
                                            </Tag>
                                        ))}
                                    
                                    {recipe.healthLabels.filter(
                                        label => label.includes('Vegan')).map(filteredLabel => (
                                            <Tag
                                                key={filteredLabel}
                                                textTransform='uppercase'
                                                fontSize={10}
                                                bgColor='yellow.400'
                                                color='gray.900'
                                            >
                                                Vegan
                                            </Tag>
                                        ))}
                                    </Flex>

                                <Flex gap={2} justify='center' wrap='wrap'>
                                    {recipe.dietLabels.map((dietLabels) => (
                                        <Tag
                                            key={dietLabels}
                                            textTransform='uppercase'
                                            fontSize={10}
                                            bgColor='green.400'
                                            color='gray.900'
                                        >
                                            {dietLabels}
                                        </Tag>
                                    ))}
                                </Flex>

                                <Text textTransform='capitalize'>Dish: {recipe.dishType}</Text>
                            </Flex>

                            <Flex justify='center'gap={2} wrap='wrap'>
                                {recipe.cautions.map((cautions) => (
                                    <Tag
                                        key={recipe.cautions}
                                        textTransform='uppercase'
                                        fontSize={10}
                                        bgColor='purple.400'
                                        color='gray.800'
                                    >                    
                                        <Text>Cautions:</Text>
                                        {cautions}
                                    </Tag>
                                ))}
                            </Flex>
                        </Stack>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            </Center>
        </>
    );    
};
```

```
import { data } from '../utils/data';
import { RecipeCard } from '../components/RecipeCard'
import {
  Center,
  Heading,
  Flex

} from '@chakra-ui/react';


export const RecipeListPage = ({ clickFn }) => {

  return (
    <Center bg='pink.600' flexDir="column" >
      <Heading size='lg' color='white'>Winc Recipe Checker</Heading>

      <Flex wrap='wrap' gap={8} justify='center'>
      {data.hits.map((recipe) => (
        <RecipeCard key={recipe} clickFn={clickFn} />
      ))}
      </Flex>

    </Center>
  );
};
```

This is the entire code on GitHub: https://github.com/Sahdia577/React-Assignment

Comment: You are passing the data directly in the `RecipeCard` component, const recipe = data.hits[0].recipe, Instead try passing the props correctly to your `RecipeCard` component

Comment: Thank you, Lokkesh. I've adjusted the code, yet it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Passing props:

```
{data.hits.map((recipe) => (
  <RecipeCard key={recipe} recipe={recipe} clickFn={clickFn} />
))}
```

Getting props:

```
export const RecipeCard = ({ clickFn, recipe }) => {
```

Comment: Thank you Konrad, I've adjusted the function and added recipe as a prop now. However, now I'm getting the following error in <RecipeListPage />:

'(parameter) recipe: any
'recipe' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)'

I'm probably making another mistake, but can't figure out what.

Comment: Update: My question is solved now, I was using recipe wrong in <RecipeListPage />.